# Extração de XML em formato correto através de GET em API

Tags: vb.net

Estou integrando um sistema com emissão de notas fiscais. Há um método de busca de XML da nota gerada. O retorno dessa consulta (GET), é um XML. Esse XML eu acesso e salvo em um arquivo para usar futuramente.

Estou conseguindo obter o retorno e acessar o xml. Porém, ele está vindo com uma formatação 'errada':

Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string>&lt;Nfse xmlns="http://www.abrasf.org.br/ABRASF/arquivos/nfse.xsd"&gt;&lt;InfNfse&gt;&lt;Numero&gt;20213&lt;/Numero&gt;
```

Sendo que o correto seria:

```
<Nfse xmlns="http://www.abrasf.org.br/ABRASF/arquivos/nfse.xsd"><InfNfse><Numero>20213</Numero>
```

Dá para notar que o **<** do xml está sendo substituído por **<** e o **<** por um **>**

Poderia tentar dar um replace para alterar isso.

Mas, para já receber esse conteúdo corretamente, há algo que posso fazer?

Minha função de leitura do xml:

```
Try

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim auth = "Basic " & buscaAPIKey()
    Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth)
    Request.ContentType = "application/xml"

    Using responseStream = Request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
        Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)

            Dim objResponse As Object = reader.ReadToEnd()

            Dim xml As String = objResponse.ToString.Trim

        End Using
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que o XML está sendo gerado de forma errada e tratando tudo como uma String, como a tag `<string>` sugere. Na hora de gerar o XML, ao invés de tratar como informações separadas a API está considerando tudo como um único valor

Comment: Trocando Request.ContentType = "application/xml" por "application/json", funcionou. Simples assim rsrs.